# How to clik on a text in the div

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Could any one please help me in selecting the text `(en_GW)` under a div?

```
<-div class="x-combo-list-inner" id="cq-gen339" style="width: 253px; height: 300px;">
<-div class="x-combo-list-item  x-combo-selected" ext:qtip="">en_GW<-/div><-div>
```

Note: Below code not working:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("x-combo-list-item  x-combo-selected")).click();
```

> Error

*Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
// xpath
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected')]")).click(); 

// css selector
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.x-combo-list-item.x-combo-selected")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2) {
  var funcs = [func1, func2];
  this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
  this.click(function() {
      var data = $(this).data();
      var tc = data.toggleclicked;
      $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
      data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 2;
  });
  return this;
   };

    $(txt5).clickToggle(function() {
alert('First handler: ' + $(this).text());
}, function() {
alert('Second handler: ' + $(this).text());

});
```

i have no of elements if clicking div count will increase. at the same time click other div first will count will be 0 ?